# Regex, 1) call last matching group 2) match exact word in a line( not partially matching in a line)

Tags: regex, uipath

UiPath base Regex - I'm trying to get the match in UiPath where it's the

(1) last match group

(2) match with whole line(not partially match in a line)

RawData
(this data it's just part of the full data)

```
MAT year 2019
MAT year 2020
MAT year 2021
year 2016
year 2017
year 2018
```

Expected outcome(1)
`MAT year 2021`

Expected outcome (2)

```
year 2017
year 2018
year 2019
```

ps# not include year from first three lines

```
year 2019
year 2020
year 2021
```

Solution (1) I tried:

get index variable from for each loop till very last, and RawData(IndexVariable).ToString

(not working, if RawData(2).ToString then working, but not all the time will be index 2)

Regex for (1): MAT to (\d\d|\d)/(\d\d|\d)/\d\d\d\d

Solution (2) I tried:

Regex for (2): Year\s\d\d\d\d

and (?!mat)(Year\s\d\d\d\d) #PS not working, look ahead

Remarks: tried also ^ and $, but this only match first line or last line, not all starting line.

Comment: @Emma, please ignore the upper or lower case, my typing error.  can you show me the multiline modifier?

Comment: @Emma, great!, seem sound my second query, how about the first Regex?

Comment: @Emma, all in my question, where label with (1), for eg. (1) last match group, Expected outcome(1), Solution (1) I tried....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

after super long process of investigation, i finalise with answer that fit for my case as well as solution for query 2 from @Emma,

Explanation for query 1 solution: for each query i making, get the last match with condition of all phrase starting with MAT has to be group together, **can't** mixed over like below:

```
MAT year 2012
year 2019
MAT year 2322
```

Solution:

> ^MAT(?:.(?!\nMAT))+$

where i'm trying to read start from MAT and next line not beginning with MAT.

Solution for query two, where only choose exact match in the line.

> ^year\s\d{4}$

a line where start from year and end with \d for 4 times

Also, learning from @Emma, combine two queries into 1, where adding | for both queries. so that run once can get both value on hand

> ^MAT(?:.(?!\nMAT))+$|^year\s\d{4}$

Answer (score 1):

I'm guessing that your desired expression might be:

```
^MAT\syear\s\d{4}(?=(?:\s*year\s\d{4}))$|^(?!MAT\s)year\s\d{4}$
```

#### [Demo](https://regex101.com/r/t0vM71/1)

---

If you wish to simplify/modify/explore the expression, it's been explained on the top right panel of [regex101.com](https://regex101.com/r/5lseEh/1). If you'd like, you can also watch in [this link](https://regex101.com/r/5lseEh/1debugger), how it would match against some sample inputs.

---

#### RegEx Circuit

[jex.im](https://jex.im/regulex/#!flags=&re=%5E(a%7Cb)*%3F%24) visualizes regular expressions:

[image]

Comment: Hi Emma, nope, this is not i'm asking for first expression, it's choosing latest year in MAT, (means MAT year 2021), not choose if starting with MAT

Comment: thanks @Emma for learning another thing from you, combine both queries into 1, as previously i'm splitting it into few